# Liquibase create table schemas in one-to-one relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, liquibase

I am trying to write a Liquibase script that would create 2 tables that have a one-to-one relationship. It is failing with the exception:

```
ERROR: relation "owner" does not exist
```

I think this happens because at the time of creation of `CAR` table, `OWNER` table is still not existant.

```
    <changeSet id="001" author="wesleyy">

        <createTable tableName="CAR">
            <column name="ID" type="bigint">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
            </column>

            <column name="OWNER_ID" type="bigint">
                <constraints 
                    foreignKeyName="OWNER_ID"
                    references="OWNER(ID)" />
            </column>
        </createTable>


        <createTable tableName="OWNER">
            <column name="ID" type="bigint">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
            </column>

            <column name="CAR_ID" type="bigint">
                <constraints 
                    foreignKeyName="CAR_ID"
                    references="CAR(ID)" />
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

The question is: am I using the foreign key reference correctly? How would I achieve this in Liquibase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cyclic foreign key constraints are usually not a good idea. But if you are 100% you need that. You need to first create both tables, and *then* add the foreign keys

```
<changeSet id="001" author="wesleyy">

  <createTable tableName="car">
      <column name="id" type="bigint">
          <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
      </column>

      <column name="owner_id" type="bigint"/>
  </createTable>


  <createTable tableName="owner">
      <column name="id" type="bigint">
          <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
      </column>

      <column name="car_id" type="bigint"/>
  </createTable>

  <addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="fk_owner2car"
                          baseTableName="owner"
                          baseColumnNames="car_id"
                          referencedTableName="car"
                          referencedColumnNames="id"/>

  <addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="fk_car2owner"
                          baseTableName="car"
                          baseColumnNames="owner_id"
                          referencedTableName="owner"
                          referencedColumnNames="id"/>

</changeSet>
```

---

Unrelated, but:

You should not write identifiers in uppercase when using Liquibase with Postgres. Liquibase thinks that you want case-sensitive upper case identifiers and will double quote all of them, making them case sensitive. Using quoted identifiers is almost always more trouble then they are worth.

Comment: What do you mean cyclic foreign key is not a good idea? How would you implement a one-to-one relationship otherwise?

Comment: Also, I'd like my schema to use upper-case identifiers. Is that possible with liquibase?

Comment: Again: using upper case identifiers in Postgres is a bad idea. It requires quoted identifiers and they are much more trouble than they are worth it